# How to plot density plots side-by-side

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, density-plot

I would like to plot multiple density plots on Python, **not** as a single plot, but as multiple plots under a single window. How can I do this with `matplotlib` of Python?

Below is what I tried, which doesn't work:

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import (plot, savefig, xlim, figure,
                              ylim, legend, boxplot, setp,
                              axes, xlabel, ylabel, xticks,
                              axvline)
import seaborn as sns

layer_list_G1_G2 = [[80.,69.,52.], [82.,83.,80.],
                [78.,81.,59.]]

def make_density(layer_list, color, nlayer):

    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 6))
    grid = plt.GridSpec(2, 6)

    ax_main = fig.add_subplot(grid[0, 0])
    
    plt.title('Density Plot of Median Stn. MC-Losses at Layers 1 - 12')
    plt.xlabel('MC-Loss')
    plt.ylabel('Density')
    plt.xlim(-0.2,0.05)
    plt.ylim(0, 85)
    min_ylim, max_ylim = plt.ylim()
    
    for j in range(nlayer):
        
        layer_list_tensor = torch.tensor(layer_list[j]) 
        
        den_j = fig.add_subplot(grid[j//6, j % 6], sharex=ax_main, sharey=ax_main)
        
                # Draw the density plot
        den_j.sns.distplot(layer_list, hist = False, kde = True,
                 kde_kws = {'linewidth': 2}, color=color)
  
        plt.axvline(layer_list_tensor.median().tolist(), color='orange', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1.5)

        plt.text(layer_list_tensor.median().tolist()*0.87, 80, 'median: {:.2f}'.format(layer_list_tensor.median().tolist()))

>>> make_density(layer_list_G1_G2, 'green', 12)
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the axes reference to the `ax=` keyword of `distplot`

eg

```
den_j = fig.add_subplot(grid[j//6, j % 6], sharex=ax_main, sharey=ax_main)
# Draw the density plot
sns.distplot(layer_list, hist = False, kde = True,
                 kde_kws = {'linewidth': 2}, color=color, ax=den_j)
#                                                         ^^^^^^^^
```